# How to validate for either form fields with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm attempting to send an error message when either the email field or the phone field of a form doesn't match the regex. The validation message shouldn't submit if either fields are filled in.

What happens right now when I go to submit the form with one of the fields filled in with the proper information the form gives me the error message and will not post the form. Once I enter the correct input into the other field it processes the form.

What I want it to do is to process the form if either the email field is filled out or the phone field is filled out with information that matches the regular expressions.

If neither of the forms are filled out correctly I want the form to throw the error message.

Here's the if statement I am working with so far.

```
<form id="contact_form"  action="" method="POST">
    <input type=hidden name="" value="">
    <input type=hidden name="" value="">

    <p class="errmsg" id="name_errormsg"></p>

    <input  id="name" maxlength="80" name="form_name" placeholder="Name" size="20" type="text" />
    <input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" placeholder="Email" size="20" type="text" />
    <input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" size="20" type="text" />

    <textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="How can we help you?"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message">
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $overlay = $(".modal-overlay");
  $modal = $(".modal-frame");


  $modal.bind('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e){
  if($modal.hasClass('state-leave')) {
    $modal.removeClass('state-leave');
  }
});
$('.form-close-button').on('click', function(){
     $overlay.removeClass('state-show');
     $modal.removeClass('state-appear').addClass('state-leave');
   });

   $('#contactformbtn').on('click', function(){
     $overlay.addClass('state-show');
     $modal.removeClass('state-leave').addClass('state-appear');
   });



var formHandle = document.forms[0];

formHandle.onsubmit = processForm;


function processForm(){


  var emailInput = document.getElementById('email');

  var emailValue = emailInput.value;


  var phoneInput = document.getElementById('phone');

  var phoneValue = phoneInput.value;




  var regexPhone = /^(1?(-?\d{3})-?)?(\d{3})(-?\d{4})$/;
  var regexEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

if((!regexPhone.test(phoneValue)) ||(!regexEmail.test(emailValue))) {
    nameErr = document.getElementById("name_errormsg");
    nameErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your phone number or a valid email address.";
    nameErr.style.color = "red";
    return false;
}

}
});
```

If any of you could point out where I went wrong this that would be great!

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Have a good day.

Comment: When do you actually call this function?

Comment: Hey Dave, Sorry I didn't include all of the code before. I thought that possibly it was an easy statement that someone might know off the top of their head. I shouldn't be making those kind of assumptions given that there could be other errors with my code tho. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: So what actually happens? What's in your JS console, anything?

Comment: Yep nothing seems to be showing up in my console.

Comment: So what actually happens? Instead of making people read and guess, particularly without a working jsfiddle (or equivalent), explain what precisely happens, what should happen, etc.

Comment: Okay I just added a description for what I would like to happen to my post. I apologize for not including that sooner. I will be sure to include this in any of my future posts.

Comment: What happens right now when I go to submit the form with one of the fields filled in with the proper information the form gives me the error message and will not post the form. Once I enter the correct input into the other field it processes the form.

What I want it to do is to process the form if either the email field is filled out or the phone field is filled out with information that matches the regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment (which should be in the question) your logic is wrong.

You're currently checking for failure of *either* field. If phone fails *or* email fails. If one field isn't filled in it'll fail because you don't allow blank.

You want to test for failure of *both* fields (with a caveat):

```
if (!regexPhone.test(phoneValue) && !regexEmail.test(emailValue)) {
    ....
```

Or you can change your regex.

The caveat is that say a user enters in a valid phone, but an invalid email: what should happen in that case? Should validation pass or fail?

Comment: What I would like to have is if both fields are filled in they are both valid before the form processes. Although if one of the fields is left blank say a client doesn't want to give their phone number or email the form will also process.

Comment: @Cakewok Then change the logic to do that--if filled it at all, it must match, e.g., if the field after stripping has content, validate it. It's not difficult, although there are multiple ways it could be implemented. Start with something that works, then make it more elegant if necessary.